# Modified Lie bracket

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lie-algebra

In a paper by Barnich, they use a different definition of the Lie bracket for vector fields at null infinity.
Can somebody please give me the intuition behind using this Lie bracket in Equation 4.12:

> $$
> \left[\xi_1,\,\xi_2\right]_M=\left[\xi_1,\,\xi_2\right]-\delta^g_{\xi_1}\xi_2+\delta^g_{\xi_2}\xi_1
> $$
>   where $\delta^g_{\xi_1}\xi_2$ denotes the variation in $\xi_2$ under the variation of the metric induced by $\xi_1$, $\delta^g_{\xi_1}g_{\mu\nu}=\mathcal{L}_{\xi_1}g_{\mu\nu}$.

Can somebody please write the variation terms explicitly, as to how to compute it.

The paper I am referring to is [arxiv.org/abs/1001.1541](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1541)

Answer (score 1):

**The reason to modify the lie bracket is the field dependence of $\zeta^\mu$.**

For the full Einstein theory, the remaining parameters $\zeta^\mu$ persevering both gauge fixing and boundary conditions generally depend on spactime metric, i.e. $$\zeta^\mu=\zeta^\mu[g].$$
Notice that the commutator of two symmetry transformations is
$$[\delta_{\zeta_1},\delta_{\zeta_2}]g_{\mu\nu}=(\delta_{\zeta_1}\delta_{\zeta_2}-\delta_{\zeta_2}\delta_{\zeta_1})g_{\mu\nu}.$$
The single variation of metric is given by original lie bracket
$$\delta_{\zeta_2}g_{\mu\nu}=\mathcal{L}_{\zeta_2}g_{\mu\nu}.$$
Owning to the field-dependence of $\zeta_2$, the second time symmetry transformation is imposed as
\begin{align}
\delta_{\zeta_1}\delta_{\zeta_2}g_{\mu\nu}&=\mathcal{L}_{\delta_{\zeta_1}\zeta_2}g_{\mu\nu}+\mathcal{L}_{\zeta_2}\delta_{\zeta_1}g_{\mu\nu}\\
&=\left(\mathcal{L}_{\delta_{\zeta_1}\zeta_2}+\mathcal{L}_{\zeta_2}\mathcal{L}_{\zeta_1}\right)g_{\mu\nu}\, .
\end{align}
Finally, we have
$$[\delta_{\zeta_1},\delta_{\zeta_1}]=\mathcal{L}_{[\zeta_2,\zeta_1]+\delta_{\zeta_1}\zeta_2-\delta_{\zeta_2}\zeta_1}\, ,$$
or say, the modified lie bracket corresponding to field variation is
$$[\zeta_1,\zeta_2]_{M}=[\zeta_1,\zeta_2]-\delta_{\zeta_1}\zeta_2+\delta_{\zeta_2}\zeta_1\, ,$$
where
$$\delta_{\zeta_1}\zeta_2[g]=\zeta_2[\mathcal{L}_{\zeta_1}g]\, .$$